# SQL Server : delete a record only if it is associated with all the groups of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, delete-row

This question is about a `DELETE` query involving two tables.

I have two tables called `TableOne` and `TableTwo`.

I have the same columns in `TableTwo` as in `TableOne`.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEONE
(
    ColumnOne INT,
    ColumnTwo INT
);

CREATE TABLE TABLETWO
(
    ColumnOne INT,
    ColumnTwo INT
 );
```

**[HERE IS SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/70f22):**

But they differ from the number of records each table contains.

In both the tables `ColumnOne` and `ColumnTwo` can contain duplicate values.

I want to delete a record in `TableTwo` based on its `ColumnTwo` value.

Fo example, suppose there are following records in `TableTwo`

```
ColumnOne  ColumnTwo
1          200
1          300
1          400
2          200
2          100
```

And there are following records in `TableOne` ( It contains the records need to be deleted)

```
ColumnOne  ColumnTwo
1          200
2          200
2          100
```

According to my requirement, only records containing 200 in `ColumnTwo` of the table `TableTwo` should be deleted.

I have written the following query to delete the records in `TableTwo`

```
DELETE FROM TableTwo
WHERE ColumnOne IN  (SELECT l.ColumnOne 
                     FROM TableOne l 
                     WHERE l.ColumnTwo = TableTwo.ColumnTwo )
```

This query deletes records containing 200 and 100 as well. But I need to delete only records containing 200 as it is associated with all the unique `ColumnOne` values in `TableTwo`.

Requirement for deletion: `TableTwo` - specified `ColumnTwo` value must be associated with all the unique values of `ColumnOne`.

Can someone help me to achieve this ?

Comment: If a record in Table2 contained "3, 200", would it also be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Column2` values in `TableOne` that are associated with all groups are found by:

```
select column2
from TableOne
group by column2
having count(*) = (select count(distinct column1 from tableone));
```

To delete these values from `TableTwo`:

```
delete from TableTwo t2
    where t2.column2 in (select column2
                         from TableOne
                         group by column2
                         having count(*) = (select count(distinct column1 from tableone))
                        );
```

Note:  if entire rows can be duplicated, then the `count(*)` should be `count(distinct column1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `EXCEPT`. With this operation you are removing matched rows from table2 and leave only those which have no corresponding association in table1. So `NOT IN` takes those removed rows only:

```
DECLARE @TABLEONE TABLE
    (
      ColumnOne INT ,
      ColumnTwo INT
    );


DECLARE @TABLETWO TABLE
    (
      ColumnOne INT ,
      ColumnTwo INT
    );


INSERT  INTO @TABLEONE
VALUES  ( 1, 200 ),
        ( 2, 200 ),
        ( 2, 100 )

INSERT  INTO @TABLETWO
VALUES  ( 1, 200 ),
        ( 1, 300 ),
        ( 1, 400 ),
        ( 2, 200 ),
        ( 2, 100 )


DELETE  FROM @TABLETWO
WHERE   ColumnOne NOT IN ( SELECT   ColumnOne
                           FROM     ( SELECT    * FROM      @TABLETWO
                                      EXCEPT
                                      SELECT    * FROM      @TABLEONE
                                    ) t )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one:

DELETE FROM @TABLETWO
WHERE ColumnTwo IN (SELECT ColumnTwo FROM @TABLETWO
GROUP BY ColumnTwo
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnOne) > 1)
AND ColumnOne IN (SELECT ColumnOne FROM @TABLEONE)
```